# Create replicas Index Algolia

Tags: php, algolia

I would like to know how to create « index replicas » with algolia.

I have index "index_a". I want create index "index_b" with same settings but when data updated in parent index (index_a) it's updated automatically in "index_b"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done using either the Algolia Dashboard or your PHP client.

Using the Algolia Dahsboard, go to the Indices page and select `index_a` in the list. Then, click on the `Replicas` tab and add a new entry named `index_b` and finally click on the green `Save` button at the top right. This will create an `index_b` that you can configure differently from `index_a`. Every record operation made to `index_a` will then be automatically replicated to `index_b`.

To do the same using the PHP client, simply populates the `replicas` setting of your index `index_a` with an array containing the string `index_b`.

For more informations, here is a link to the official documentation https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/ranking/sorting/?language=php#algolia-replica-indexes.